# Connection Attributes in AWS DMS Endpoint through Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-dms

I'm working on creating DMS-related infrastructure in AWS (replication instance, endpoints, tasks, etc.) with Terraform.  In the process of editing the **Extra Connection Attributes** for an S3 endpoint, I'm creating them like so:

```
extra_connection_attributes="addColumnName=true;bucketFolder=foldername;bucketName=bucketname;cdcPath=undefined;compressionType=GZIP;csvDelimiter=,;csvRowDelimiter=\n;encryptionMode=SSE_S3;"
```

When I run Terraform plan, it returns the correct output; however, when I get to the actual endpoint instance attributes in AWS, it shows this:

```
bucketFolder=bucketfolder;bucketName=bucketname;compressionType=NONE;csvDelimiter=,;csvRowDelimiter=\n;
```

What could be the reason that some of the values are changing and some aren't there at all?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some open tickets related to this that may be the cause.

[terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws#8000](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8000)

[terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws#8009](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8009)

[terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws#8807](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8807)